# cannot display value from memory in MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following code:

```
<div>
        UserName: @{ 
                ((Person>)CacheDispatcher.LoadFromCache("LoggedInUser")); 
             } 
    </div>
```

It does not yield any username at all. I put a break point and definitely i can see the CacheDispatcher is returning a value (which is the username) but when the page rendered, it does not display a value.   any suggestions?

Comment: maybe try htmledit see if the value appears

Comment: thanks for giving me a clue.. i use @Html.Label instead

Answer (score 0):

this is so annoying.. the downside of asp.net MVC that you cannot render a string without HTML helper.. I fixed this by using @Html.Label to yield the value..

Answer (score 0):

The problem didn't need to be solved using a @Html.Label.

You should have used something like:

```
@((Person>)CacheDispatcher.LoadFromCache("LoggedInUser")).ToString();
```

Instead of:

```
@{ 
    ((Person>)CacheDispatcher.LoadFromCache("LoggedInUser"))
}
```

Your original never renders anything to the response. That is just a block of code.